# PosgreSQL prevent from entering some "table" mode

Tags: postgresql, psql

When I make a `SELECT` in **PostgreSQL** console, I'm entering a different mode where I scroll in table. How to prevent this mode, just return the data and have the command prompt ready to enter a new command, like in the example below ?

```
mydb=# SELECT * FROM public.foo;

 id | col
----+-----
  1 | 123
  2 | 456

mydb=#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're referring to the ["pager"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager) which allows you to go through large sets of results page-by-page. Usually you want this else if you select large sets of results they'll whizz by. A pager is an important part of working on the command line.

You can turn it off in [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) with `\pset pager off`.

Comment: That's it, thanks! I agree it's convenient but I need to show the content of a few (short) tables in a one-liner, so I need to disable it temporarily.

Comment: @DevonDahon In that case if you pipe the commands in and read them from stdout it will not page. `echo 'SELECT * FROM public.foo;' | psql database`